# Help me with basis and dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are vector subspaces of $V$, and let $C$ and $D$ be bases for $A$ and $B$, respectively.

Then is it true that

1. $C \cup D$ is a basis for $A+B$?
2. $\operatorname{dim}(A+B) \le |C| + |D|$ (where $|\cdot|$ denotes cardinality)?

I am really bad at dimensions and bases.
Can you help me to understand such questions and how to deal with them?

Comment: For (1), no it is not true.  Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are the same space, with $D = \{ -x \mid x\in C\}$.  Then $C \cup D$ is not a linearly independent set, and therefore not a basis for $A+B$.  (2) is correct, as $C\cup D$ will span $A + B$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\Bbb{R}$ as $\Bbb{R}$-vectorspace. Two basis are given by $C:=\{1\}, D:=\{2\}$. Can you answer your first question from here?

For the second question notice that $C\cup D$ is a generating system for $A+B$.

Answer (score 0):

In questions like this, it's always good to consider cases where $A$ and $B$ have non-trivial intersection, as well as cases where they intersect trivially.

Suppose $V=\Bbb R^3$, and take $C=\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$ and $D=\{(0,1,1), (0,0,1)\}$. Do you see how this furnishes a counterexample for (1)?

For (2), all you need to show is that $C\cup D$ *spans* $A+B$. Can you write an arbitrary element of $A+B$ in terms of basis vectors of $A$ and $B$?

Answer (score 0):

There is a linear map $\;\begin{aligned}[t]f:A\times B&\longrightarrow A+B\\ (u,v)&\longmapsto u-v\end{aligned}$.

The kernel of $f$ is the subspace
$\;\bigl\{(u,v)\in A\times B\mid u=v\bigr\}$, hence it is isomorphic to $A\cap B\;$ by the linear map:
$$A\cap B\longrightarrow  A\times B,\enspace u\longmapsto (u,u).$$
Now $A\times B$ has dimension equal to $\dim A+\dim B$. Indeed, a basis of $A\times B$ is the union of   $C'=C\times\{0\}$ and $D'=\{0\}\times D$.

By the *rank-nullity theorem*, we have
$$\dim(A+B)=\dim A+\dim B - \dim A\cap B,$$
and we see $C\cup B$ is a basis for $A+B$ if and only if $A\cap B=\{0\}$, i.e. if and only if the sum $A+B$ is *direct*.